# Please help stopping the form action

Tags: php, forms

Check function not work !! Please help

```
  <php?
    function Check (){

      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
     {      
    if (!is_numeric($_POST["num1"])) 
    {
    $Err1 = "Num1 is not numeric"; 
    }
  if (!is_numeric($_POST["num2"])) 
  {
   $Err2 = "Num2 is not numeric"; 
  } 
  if ( $Err1 = $Err2 = ""){
  return true;}
  else  return false;
 }

return false;

}
 ?>
```

--First time using stack overflow . Need to follow the post rule ?

`<Form  method="post" onSubmit="return Check();" action="MyPhp.php">                            
    </Form>`

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client, i.e. the users web browser. You can't get JS to directly run a PHP function (or anything else for that matter).

Comment: Please get aware what client-side and server-side programming is. PHP is server-side. `onsubmit` is a client-side javascript event - which should, by the way, not be attached via a html attribute.

Comment: Hmm i'm just new to Web Coding .... I Forgot That Basic .. !

Comment: `if ($Err1 = $Err2 = "")` looks terrible.  Examine this.

Comment: I can't stop the form action but i found a way to check num 1 and num2 status on the next page , if they don't meet requirement auto back to previous page 

<pre>

Answer (score 0):

This code is to check if num1 and num2 is not numberic , if num1 divide by 0 , if calculation type is not selected then back

```
 <?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
 {
  if (!is_numeric($_POST["num1"])) 
  { echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
         history.go(-1);
        </script>
    ";

  }
 elseif (!is_numeric($_POST["num2"])) 
 {
   echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
         history.go(-1);
        </script>
    ";
 } 
 elseif ($_POST["num2"] == 0 && $_POST['rb1'] =="Divide")
 {
   echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
         history.go(-1);
        </script>
    ";
 } 

elseif (! isset($_POST['rb1'])) {
   echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
         history.go(-1);
        </script>
    ";
```

}
 }